# search copy and paste the row in vba

Tags: excel

I want to search the data and copy the entire row to another sheet. I am able to find the required detail and able to get the address of the cell. Please advise as how to copy this row and past in last row of another sheet.

```
Set cell = Sheet2.Range("D1:D1048576").Find("5034030", LookIn:=xlValues)
MsgBox cell.Address
```

Comment: Does the table you are copying from have a fixed number of columns?

Comment: Last row based on what column?